# Is there a function in mapreduce or java to automatically identify data types in csv files

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am relatively new to mapreduce but I want to make a mapreduce program that can read relatively different types of csv files and do some calculations such as min, max,average,sum,mode,standard deviation and then display them on a website. But to do this I need to be able to identify the columns' datatypes. If the datatype is a `writable` then do something and if text do something else. Can somebody advise me how can I do it?

Comment: I have one suggestion -- use Spark, not MR. And, after reading .csv file into dataframe, use `.summary()` or `.describe()` to get basic stats about all or selected columns. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#summary-java.lang.String...-

Comment: @mazaneicha..I cannot use other things I have to use mapreduce